# Typing question/answer via iPhone very slow

Tags: discussion, bug, design

I've just typed an answer on AD and it's way slower than typing a question or answer on this meta for example.

I am using Mobile Safari browser and not enabling the mobile theme - so it's basically the full site css/js on the iOS 7 mobile Safari that is not performing well when typing.

Can the custom font be disabled for the textareas please?

**Important edit:** please note I'm not 100% sure it is the font. Both are ***consolas***, but something is causing this. Someone who could troubleshoot this, would be awesome.

Comment: What model iPhone & what version of iOS are you using? Are you using Safari (mobile or full) or the iOS app (and is it alpha or release)?

Comment: iOS7, iPhone 5. I'm using the native Safari app.

Comment: I've been bugged by this before. How did you determine it was the custom font causing the slowness? (also good catch that it's not affecting the meta as much as it does the main site)

Comment: Interesting, I can't reproduce this, even on an otherwise very slow iPhone 4. I presume you're using the full view where the text area has a monospaced font? If so, I presume the problem doesn't occur in the mobile view? Does this slowness occur in any other sites with a custom font in a text area? Is the device jailbroken?

Comment: @bmike as software developer I assume it's the custom font. I'm not 100% certain, but something is different on AD than it is on this meta or SO.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside the device is not jailbroken and as per bmike's comment I'm not the only one - so I doubt this is a device error (as meta does not show this behavior).

Comment: I was asking if it was jailbroken as I'm unable to reproduce this myself and would have asked if you could do some debugging. I understand that you're not the only one, yet my other questions are still valid? Are you using mobile or full view?

Comment: Full, but meta is mobile. Can I toggle this?  Yes ofc your questions are valid